# didReceiveData not getting called when downloading images

Tags: ios, ios4

I've seen many post on this topic, but none of them helped in resolving the problem. I am having a download.php file on webserver which I use for downloading images stored on the server. The php does this by splitting the task into two step.
The first step is I send the user info and the php returns the ids of images associated with the user. In the second step on basis of those ids I send another request to the same php page and request image of a particular id one by one.
This approach works well when used in html or in my android code, so I am sure that there's no issue in the php.

When I do send request to php from ios code, the first step of getting image ids works well, but requesting image doesn't work at all. The didReceieveData callback never gets called. Here's what I am doing -

```
- (void)downloadImages:(NSInteger)imageNo{
    NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"user=%@&download=%@&imageId=%d", userName, @"true",imageNo];

    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]
                                    initWithURL:[NSURL
                                                 URLWithString:@"MYWEBSERVER/download.php"]];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    currentDownMode = DOWN_IMAGE;

    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}
```

Here's what I am having in my php page -

```
function download()
{
    global $folder_path, $user_id, $image_table, $sql_folder_path;
    $fileID = $_POST["imageId"];
    $sql="SELECT fileName,filePath FROM $image_table WHERE fileId='$fileID'";
    $query = mysql_query($sql) or die($sql . ' - ' . mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    $im = file_get_contents("../" . $row[1] . $row[0]);
    header('content-type: image/gif'); 
    echo $im;
}
```

Comment: Is [didFailWithError] getting called?

Comment: No it didn't, I get didReceiveResponse and didFinishloading callback, but no didFailWithError